# Typescript Redux does not let me add children inside <Provider> tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

[image]

This is the error I get and I have no idea why, so please help. I will add the snippet of code and the package.json bellow:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { store } from "../state";
    import RepositoriesList from "./RepositoriesList";

    function App() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <div>
            <h1>Search for a Package</h1>
            <RepositoriesList />
          </div>
        </Provider>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this issue with Node 16.16:

```
    "react-redux": "7.2.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.16",
```

seems to have resolved upgrading both packages:

```
    "react-redux": "7.2.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
```

(or just `react-redux` 8.x which no longer requires @types/react-redux).

I'm unsure of details/reasons, but their seems to be a flag for this at the top of the docs now: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript which links to this thread https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1094565891